Data doesn't get removed by ARC in swift
I have a for-loop that does some thing and allocates about 200MB during its execution.
The data won't be deallocated even minutes after the for-loops execution.
It only changes data and doesn't create new data that needs to be stored afterwards.
Here's my code:
   func mutateNetwork(){
        let conCount = currentWorkflowHolder.workflowData[currentWorkflowHolder.workflowData.count-1][currentWorkflowHolder.workflowData[currentWorkflowHolder.workflowData.count-1].count-1].thirdConnections.count-1
        for _ in 0...50{
            let arg1 = Int.random(in: 0...conCount)
            
            let arg2 = Int.random(in: 0...currentWorkflowHolder.workflowData[currentWorkflowHolder.workflowData.count-1][currentWorkflowHolder.workflowData[currentWorkflowHolder.workflowData.count-1].count-1].thirdConnections[conCount].count)
            currentWorkflowHolder.workflowData[0][0].thirdConnections[arg1][arg2] = Float.random(in: -50...50)
        }
        
    }

It's a bit messy due to me trying to erase potential problems.
I've tried:

using an autoreleasepool{} but it didn't help
other solutions I found seemed to be focused on deallocating RAM in the loop (but it didn't work)

Edit:
currentWorkflowHolder is a property, but it doesn't have a get{} or a set{}.

How did you test the autoreleasepool{} code? Depending on where you put it, it might change. Also, if you keep a value currentWorkflowHolder (I guess it's a property), it will stay in memory.

I tried to put it into the loop and outside the loop. Yes, currentWorkflowHolder is a property, but I don't add a new item to the array but override one instead and even if I added it should be about 200 bytes, not mega bytes.

This isn't JavaScript, we have better tools for getting the last element of something :) currentWorkflowHolder.workflowData[currentWorkflowHolder.workflowData.count-1] can just be currentWorkflowHolder.workflowData.last!

This happened while I tried to minimise room for mistake and I just copied my code from setting the element (since currentWorkflowHolder.workflowData.last! can't be set).


It only changes data and doesn't create new data that needs to be stored afterwards.

This isn't quite true in the way you're probably thinking. This code is almost certainly doing a massive number of allocations and copies. A highly simplified version of this code would be:
xs[1][2] = 4 

This is not a "two-dimensional Array" that you are just modifying a single element of. This is an Array of Arrays, and you are modifying both the nested Array and the containing Array. It works roughly like:
var row = xs[1]
row[2] = 4  // This is **very** likely to make a copy of all of row.
xs[1] = row // This will probably make a copy of all of xs.

Given all the nesting going on here, you're almost certainly making copies of copies of everything, including your "holder" structs. Those should all be released in the end so that this would only represent a short-term memory spike and very poor performance.
When you say "the data won't be deallocated," how are you checking that? If you're just looking at total reported memory usage, that's normal. When your program allocates memory and then releases it, it may not be returned to the OS immediately if there's no memory pressure. This is an optimization because requesting memory from the OS is expensive, and the system assumes if you asked for it once, you may need it again. The Allocations tool in Instruments is generally a better way to check memory usage. Xcode's memory "dashboard" is also usually pretty good for this. But things like Activity Monitor can be extremely misleading. Debug builds are also not very aggressive about releasing memory, though they should eventually, and do not optimize away certain copies that Release builds do.
The way to fix this is to redesign your data storage. As a starting point, if this is really a matrix rather than an array of arbitrary-length arrays, the correct way to implement that is a single, flat Array that you compute the index into by multiplying the row times the width, and adding the column (or vice versa depending on the order you want).
If redesigning your data structures is too hard, then you can redesign your algorithm to walk over the data one time and construct a single new copy. For each element, you would decide whether to copy the old value or assign a new value. This will make the system O(n) and require only one copy.
Note that autoreleasepool doesn't really apply unless some of the things here are NSObject subclasses and make use of autoreleased objects. Broadly speaking, Swift structs do not use the autorelease pool. (This can depend a bit on what kinds of methods you call, but looking at this code I wouldn't expect any autoreleases.)
